# Why choice.set is used instead if Choice.set?

Tags: python, django

I am learning django from documentation.

Following is the `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

This is executed in the shell:

```
 q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> q.choice_set.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

Here `why q.choice_set` is used instead of `q.Choice_set`?

Is `choice_set` some inbuilt function or it is used because of Choice in `models.py`, if so why its first letter is taken in small case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its lowercase because the main coding standard that is followed in Python is Pep8, and both [functionnames](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) and [instance variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) as dictated by that should be lowercase.

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

Answer (score 2):

Because [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) says so:

> If a model has a `ForeignKey`, instances of the foreign-key model will have access to a `Manager` that returns all instances of the first model. By default, this `Manager` is named `FOO_set`, where `FOO` is the source model name, lowercased.